# Windows Scheduler: Task Start Failed

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I'm trying to learn about task scheduling in Windows 10, so I set myself the task of trying to schedule a script that writes a blank file called `test.txt` to the user's home directory.

I did this by creating a task that executes `Out-File -FilePath $HOME\test.txt`:

[image]

However, when I try to execute this task manually I see some errors:

[image]

I've also confirmed that the `test.txt` file wasn't created. The error description looks like this:

> Task Scheduler failed to launch action "Out-File" in instance "{32b4ec9b-49e8-441a-852d-8332f0a118d5}" of task "\TestTask". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942402.

According to [another SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/559288/what-causes-scheduled-task-error-2147942402/559314) This issue is caused by a "File Not Found" error. I thought maybe it couldn't find the `Out-File` command so I tried changing the command to `echo "test" >> $HOME\test.txt` but this didn't seem to have any effect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I really should have read the answer to the question I linked better: [What causes scheduled task error 2147942402?](https://serverfault.com/questions/559288/what-causes-scheduled-task-error-2147942402/559314)

This answers my question:

> The reason is that MOVE is not a program, but a native command in cmd.
>
> It should be:
>
> Program: "cmd.exe" Arguments: "/c move C:\Windows\Temp*.foo
> E:\Foo_blah_blah_blah_blah\Foo2"

In my case what I should have done was execute the command `powershell.exe` with the arguments `-Command "Out-File -FilePath $HOME\test.txt"`, which works great.